# How to change the user.email and user.name in git?

Tags: git, commit

I have pushed some commits to remote server with old user.name 'yesgo', and user.email 'yesgo@domain.com', and I need to change the change the user.name to 'newname', user.email to 'newname@domain.com' in old commits that I have pushed, so can I do this, and how? many thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but it involves rewriting the hash ids of all of your commits. Do other people already have copies of your old commits? Rewriting the commits will cause some problems for them if that is the case.

Comment: @Cupcake thanks for your help, all gits are only for me, no others have copies. how should I rewrite the hash ids of all of my commits?